# Все действия внутри одного блок с классом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок:

```js
var $size = 155;
if ($('.review-cont').height() > $size) {
  $('.review-cont').addClass('re-hide');
  $('<span>', {
    text: 'Подробнее',
    class: 're-open'
  }).appendTo('.review-bottom');
  $(".re-open").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.review-cont').toggleClass('re-hide').toggleClass('re-full');
    var $button = $(this);
    $button.text($button.text() == "Подробнее" ? "Закрыть" : "Подробнее");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review">
  <div class="review-top">имг</div>
  <div class="review-middle">
    <p class="review-name">текст</p>
    <p class="review-location">еще текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="review-bottom">
    <div class="review-cont">КОНТЕНТ</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Таких блоков много. Из задачи всё просто - если указанный блок превышает указанную в скрипте высоту, то добавляем класс и кнопку.

Но проблема в том, что если какой-то из множества блоков укладывается в высоту, указанную в скрипте, то скрипт не отрабатывает не только у данного блока, но и во всех остальных.

Как сделать, чтобы высота считалась в каждом отдельном случаи независимо? Предполагаю использование `this`, но не понял, как его приладить.

Comment: каких именно блоков много? в какой из блоков _review-bottom_ должен вставляться создаваемый спан?

Comment: блоков review много и отрабатывать скрипт должен в каждом из них независимо.
спан должен вставляться в тот review-bottom у которого review-cont попадает под условие >155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Метод *height*](http://api.jquery.com/height/) возвращает значение высоты для **первого** элемента в коллекции

> **Description:** Get the current computed height for the **first** element in the set of matched elements.

Для проверки *всех* нужно использовать [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Кроме того для вставки span, так же надо брать элемент относительно текущего. в данном случае подойдет [метод parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

---

Пример:

```js
var $size = 155;
$('.review-cont').each(function() {
  var $review = $(this);
  if ($review.height() > $size) {
    $review.addClass('re-hide');
    $('<span>', {
        text: 'Подробнее',
        class: 're-open'
      }).appendTo($review.parent())
      .click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.review-cont').toggleClass('re-hide').toggleClass('re-full');
        var $button = $(this);
        $button.text($button.text() == "Подробнее" ? "Закрыть" : "Подробнее");
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review">
  <div class="review-top">имг</div>
  <div class="review-middle">
    <p class="review-name">текст</p>
    <p class="review-location">еще текст</p>
  </div>
  <div class="review-bottom">
    <div class="review-cont">КОНТЕНТ</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а в виде кода можно?
вот я, исходя из вашего ответа, попробовал так:

 $('.review-cont', this).each(function() { 
  if($(this).height() > $size){

Но результат совсем не такой вышел.

Comment: @Aaron, не такой - это какой? что именно еще ты менял?

Comment: не так, значит, что условие сработало, но спан и классы добавились вообще во всех блоках review-bottom, а не только в том, который попал под условие

Comment: @Aaron, обновил ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Я бы примерно так сделал -

```js
let listItemAll = Array.from( document.body.querySelectorAll( '.autoresize-content-container' ) );

const LIST_ITEM_MAX_HEIGHT = 36;

function listItemSizeValid(element){
  return  element.scrollHeight > LIST_ITEM_MAX_HEIGHT;
} 
function setElementSizeAllowedTask( element ){
  element.dataset.state = "max-size"
}

listItemAll
  .filter( listItemSizeValid )
  .forEach( setElementSizeAllowedTask );
```

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
  
  display: inline-flex;
  
  justify-content: center;
}

.list-item {
  max-height: 80px;
  
  width: 100px;
}

.autoresize-content-container[data-state="default-size"] > button {
  display: none;
}

.autoresize-content-container[data-state="max-size"] {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list-item">
      <div class="autoresize-content-container" data-state="default-size">
        <span>
          some text
          some text
        </span>
        <button>развернуть</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <div class="autoresize-content-container" data-state="default-size">
        <span>
          some text
          some text
          some text
          some text
        </span>
        <button>развернуть</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <div class="autoresize-content-container" data-state="default-size">
        <span>
          some text
          some text
        </span>
        <button>развернуть</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <div class="autoresize-content-container" data-state="default-size">
        <span>
          some text
          some text
          some text
          some text
        </span>
        <button>развернуть</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <div class="autoresize-content-container" data-state="default-size">
        <span>
          some text
          some text
        </span>
        <button>развернуть</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <div class="autoresize-content-container" data-state="default-size">
        <span>
          some text
          some text
          some text
          some text
        </span>
        <button>развернуть</button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

Из-за того что я не хочу писать css для для контейнера контента, который не входит в суть вопроса, я не стал уменьшать размеры, как в моем предыдущем примере, чтобы Вы увидели кнопки, которые есть только у контейнеров превысивших высоту.

Особое внимание на то как устанавливается кнопка. В `js` для это нужно лишь изменить флаг с `default-size` на `max-size` и тогда к контейнеру применяются стили, которые прописаны для подсветки фона.

И хватит уже использовать позавчерашнюю `jQ`, чистый `js` уже давно превзошел её.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, у меня итак вся стилизация идёт через css, но как вы правильно заметили узнать высоту можно только через js. Свой css я в вопросе не стал приводить, ибо он не имел значения.
Работаю с jquery, потому как на нём хоть что-то могу, на чистом js вообще провал.
Код выше отвечает требованиям в плане функционирования. Хотелось бы узнать, вы можете его представить в виде чистого js?

Comment: @Aaron ну а кто виноват в том, что вы начали учить библиотеку, а не язык? Это получается что Вы не учитесь программировать, а учитись быть библиотекарем. Самый момент остановится и подумать что Вам нужно.

Comment: Да я никого и не обвинял, просто уточнил почему jq, а не js изначально.
По поводу вашего варианта - IE ругается на первую строчку js вываливая
"Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод "from"".

И насколько я понимаю с data атрибутами всё что ниже IE 11 - в пролёте? Вообще я за то, чтобы выбросить IE из оборота и уж тем более всё что до 11 версии, но нельзя.

Comment: А препроцессоры использовать почему не хотите? Препроцессоры сейчас уже стандарт и даже начинающие обязаны ими пользоваться чтобы не терять время впустую. Сейчас Вы много время потратите на jq, а затем Вам покажется что его Вы уже знаете и готовы перейти к другим библиотекам, а с их помощью можно писать только на чистом js и их использование совместно с jq считается дурным тоном. Спрашивается для чего вообще jq? А тут две причины - первая это не стоит учится по старым урокам и вторая если Вам не её не впарить, то кто же будет дешевые убогие сайты делать?